# How can I animate this div to slide left when the 'right' button is clicked jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

How can I get the recent container or the thmbnl-recent divs to slide left abit every time the right button is clicked without the scrollbar to create a sliding div effect like youtube has.

```js
$('button').onclick(function(){
   $('#thmbnl-recent').animate({left: "-=500"}, 2000);
});
```

```css
 /*----------Recent Projects----------*/
    
    
    #recent-container {
     width: 950px;
     height: 275px;
     background-color: ;
     border: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-color: #d8d8d8;
     margin-bottom: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
    
    }
    
    .thmbnl-recent {
     padding: 20px 13px 0px 13px;
     width: 190px;
     display: inline-block;
     border: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-color: #d8d8d8;
     background-color: white;
     transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
     cursor: pointer;
    
    }
    
    .thmbnl-recent h1 {
     text-align: center;
     font-family: "calibri light";
     font-size: 24px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 10px 0px;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    
    #recent-title {
     font-family: "calibri light";
     text-align: center;
     width: 950px;
     background-color: white;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 10px 0px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 2;
     border-top: solid;
     border-right: solid;
     border-left: solid;
     box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     border-width: 1px;
     border-color: #d8d8d8;
    }
    
    .thmbnl-recent:hover {
     background-color: #e8e8e8;
     transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .thmbnl-recent:active {
     background-color: #d1d1d1;
    }
    
    
    
    /*--------SLIDE IMAGE---------*/
    
    #gallery-container {
     margin: 75px 0px 45px 0px;
     text-align: center;
     border: solid;
     border-color: #d8d8d8;
     border-width: 1.5px;
    }
    
    #slide-section {
     text-align: center;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    
    }
    
    #gallery-container h1{
     padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
     margin: 0;
     font-family: "calibri light";
     font-size: 30px;
     border-bottom: solid;
     background-color: white;
     border-color: #d8d8d8;
     border-width: 1.5px;
     box-shadow: 0 7px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     z-index: 3;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    #imgrow {
     margin-top: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
    
    }
    
    button{
     margin-top: 280px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="recent-title">Recent Projects</h2>

<div id="recent">
 <div id="recent-container">
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
 </div>

 <button>right</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Open your console, it says : `Error : $('button').onclick is not a function`. You want to use `$('button').click`. Second error : `#thmbnl-recent` does not exist.

Comment: You need to select `.thmbnl-recent` for class, and `#thmbnl-recent` for id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with jQuery and CSS3 animation :

```js
var $slider = $("#recent-container")

$("button").click( function() {
 $slider.css("left","-=195px")
})
```

```css
h1{
   font-size : 0.8rem
}

#recent {
  border: #f00 dashed 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 230px;
}
#recent #recent-container {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#recent #recent-container .thmbnl-recent {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="recent-title">Recent Projects</h2>

<div id="recent">
 <div id="recent-container">
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="thmbnl-recent">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
   <h1>Sample</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<button>right</button>
```

Comment: Thank You very much, that looks great and Ill use this!

Comment: You're welcome, this is a very quick example, but feel free to adapt the code, of course.